# Java 8 - Coletar elementos de uma lista

Tags: java, array, expressões-lambda, lista, java-8

Bom dia.

Gostaria de coletar elementos específicos de uma lista. Poderia fazer do estilo Java 7, mas estou curioso para saber como faria no estilo Java 8.

Por exemplo:

[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]] = Um ArrayList de Object[]

Coletando as posições 0 e 1 de cada elemento do arrayList, o resultado esperado:

[[1, 2], [1, 2], [4, 5]]

Tente da seguinte forma, mas a lista permanece inalterada:

```
lista = lista.stream().peek((Object[] e) -> e = new Object[] {e[0], e[1]}).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Olá, Breno! Bem-vindo ao [pt.so]! Esse código não funciona porque ele simplesmente altera a referência da variável (parâmetro) `e` para um novo array, sem contudo alterar a lista original. Essa técnica funcionaria talvez se Java suportasse ponteiros.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Porque a lista não muda

O método `peek` retorna a mesma lista original que, neste caso, permanece inalterada porque a sua função lambda não altera os elementos.

O trecho `(Object[] e)` declara um parâmetro para a função. Em Java, se um parâmetro recebe uma atribuição de um novo valor isso **não altera a referência original** como talvez possa acontecer com um ponteiro para ponteiros em C.

Portanto, o trecho `e = new Object[] {e[0], e[1]}` cria um novo array que é entretanto descartado logo que a função termina.

O código da função lambda do `peek` é equivalente ao seguinte trecho:

```
void accept(Object[] e) {
    e = new Object[] {e[0], e[1]}
}
```

Essa confusão sobre parâmetros é comum no Java, tanto que alguns autores recomendam sempre usar o modificador `final` em parâmetros, para não confundi-los com variáveis locais e para não achar que você pode modificá-los.

## Solução

Entretanto, o método `map` pode ser usado em conjunto com a função lambda para atingir o objetivo desejado.

Exemplo:

```
lista.stream()
    .map((Object[] e) -> new Object[] {e[0], e[1]})
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

O método `map`, diferente do `peed`, tem o objetivo de criar uma nova lista baseada nos elementos modificados do vetor original.

A função lambda recebe os elementos da lista original e deve retornar algum valor que será usado para montar a nova lista.

Note que não são necessários um `return` ou uma atribuição para `e`. O valor "retornado" pelo comando de dentro da função lambda já é considerado um retorno.

Código de exemplo completo:

```
List<Object[]> lista = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
lista.add(new Object[] {1, 2, 3});
lista.add(new Object[] {1, 2, 3});
lista.add(new Object[] {4, 5, 6});
List<Object[]> novaLista = lista.stream()
    .map((Object[] e) -> new Object[] {e[0], e[1]}).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente. Inicialmente eu tinha visto o 'map', mas o que eu encontrava era apenas mapeado um único valor, não múltiplos.